# MySQL Subquery in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am using MySQL and am getting an error when if I try to excute a subquery... my subquery is as follows:

> sponsor_id columns contains 10 record with id (auto increment).

```
SELECT * FROM user where id=(select id from user where sponsor_id ='10002')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error msg?

Comment: You need to use IN or EXISTS instead of =.

Comment: you have to use `IN` instead of the `=`

Answer (score 5):

use **IN** instead of  = .

```
SELECT * FROM user where id IN (select id from user where sponsor_id ='10002' AND id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: the result is limited to sponsor_id='10002'... I want so select all the id..<br>  select all id if sponsor_id = '10002' , sponsor id contains 10 records.. so in result 10 id should be selected..

Comment: This is because your question also contains WHERE condition. If you remove that than you result will be global

Comment: But i want result 10 records.. because sponsor_id ='10002' contains 10 record.. so 10 new id's... so it should fetch 10 records ...

Comment: can you create SQL fiddle for this? because above query must work for 10 records.

Comment: please give me your email: i will send the sql file

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your subquery is most probably returning more than one values. It should return only one value if you are using the equals to operator.

Else use the `IN` clause as:

```
SELECT * FROM user where id IN (select id from user where sponsor_id ='10002')
```

### Edit:

You may also use an `INNER JOIN` or any other `JOIN` for that matter that suits your purpose.

Comment: But i want result 10 records.. because sponsor_id ='10002' contains 10 record.. so 10 new id's... so it should fetch 10 records ...

Comment: @user3133175, use the `IN` clause or you may use an `INNER JOIN` if that suits your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the error because `'='` will operate on a single value not on the multiple values.so use `'IN'` opeartor or make sure that your subquery returns only a single value while using `'='`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM user where id IN (select id from user where sponsor_id ='10002')
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM user where id =(select id from user where sponsor_id ='10002' Limit 1)
```

Comment: But i want result 10 records.. because sponsor_id ='10002' contains 10 record.. so 10 new id's... so it should fetch 10 records ...